# Python TkInter Label with TextVariable and Text

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I want to print the runtime with `seconds` string. But this code is not working.

```
runTime = StringVar()
RT = Label(window, textvariable=runTime, text="seconds")
RT.pack()
```

Output :

```
0.00985...
```

I want to change the output into :

```
0.00985... seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this ,

```
runTime = StringVar()
RT = Label(window, textvariable=runTime)
RT.pack()

runtime.set(str(<your time variable>)+'seconds')
```

Answer (score 1):

Both answers are wrong. This is how it is supposed to be done:

```
time = tk.IntVar()
time.set(5)

runTime = tk.StringVar()

runTime.set(str(time .get()) + ' seconds')
```

Answer (score -1):

(Way to late) Try this

```
runTime = ""
RT = Label(window, text=runTime + "seconds")
RT.pack()
```